# Make bigger svg circle

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an example of svg circle. But I dont know how to make bigger it in radius. I need this example cuz there are border-gradient with transperent inside. And I need not six parts, I need 12 parts. Please can somebody help me with it?

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <svg style="margin-top: 100px" width="300" height="300">
    <linearGradient id="linearColors1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors2" x1="0.5" y1="0" x2="0.5" y2="1">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors3" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors4" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors5" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearColors6" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
       <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
   <path d="M150 10 a120 120 0 0 1 103.9230 60"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors1)" stroke-width="20" />
  <path d="M253.9230 70 a120 120 0 0 1 0 120"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors2)" stroke-width="20" />
  <path d="M253.9230 190 a120 120 0 0 1 -103.9230 60"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors3)" stroke-width="20" />
  <path d="M150 250 a120 120 0 0 1 -103.9230 -60"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors4)" stroke-width="20" />
  <path d="M46.077 190 a120 120 0 0 1 0 -120"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors5)" stroke-width="20" />
  <path d="M46.077 70 a120 120 0 0 1 103.9230 -60"
        fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors6)" stroke-width="20" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Stan, remove the `width` and `height` from the `<svg>` and use `viewbox="0 0 300 300"` instead. This way the parent `<div>` can determine the size of the SVG. Make the parent `div` any size and the SVG sizes with it....(`<svg style="margin-top: 100px" viewbox="0 0 300 300">`). For the 12 part, you will need to reconstruct the entire circle as `path`s are being used. You could try to change the `60` and `-60` into `30` and `-30` and duplicate the code, but I'm not sure it will work out.

Comment: With the bigger raidus thanks, it`s works! With more parts not working.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that (tested, actually). Involves some trigonometry => 360/6 = 60, 360/12 = 30 (polar to cartesian stuff). I'm really bad at math and can't focus at 3:30am...after a few glasses of ...milk ;-). There are a few solutions for 'SVG colorwheel' using that math (using it myself, just can't find it). Will get back at it later today (unless someone else came up with a solution). Here's link a with more on that: [A simple pie chart in SVG](https://medium.com/hackernoon/a-simple-pie-chart-in-svg-dbdd653b6936) Sorry for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it using svg: I am creating a arc representing the 12th part of a circle. Next I'm using the arc 12 times every time using a different gradient for the stroke.

In order to make a bigger circle you can either change the width of the svg element or in javascript change the `r`.

Of coarse you'll have to write the gradients you want for the arcs 7 to 11

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
let r = 120;
let n = 12;
let a = 360/n;
let arad = 2*Math.PI/n
let points = []
let p1={
    x:r*Math.cos(0),
    y:r*Math.sin(0)
}
let p2={
    x:r*Math.cos(arad),
    y:r*Math.sin(arad)
}

  let path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'path');
  let d = `M${p1.x},${p1.y}A${r},${r} 0 0 1 ${p2.x},${p2.y}`;
  path.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
  path.setAttribute("id","thepath");
  theDefs.appendChild(path);

for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
  let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
  use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#thepath');
  use.setAttribute("stroke",`url(#linearColors${i})`)
  use.setAttribute("transform",`rotate(${a*i})`);
  svg.appendChild(use);
}
```

```css
use{stroke-width:20px;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" style="margin-top: 100px" viewBox="-150 -150 300 300" width="300">
<defs id="theDefs">
<linearGradient id="linearColors0" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors1" x1="0.5" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors2" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors3" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors4" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors5" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors6" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors7" x1="0.5" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors8" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors9" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors10" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors11" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="1">
<stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
<stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same using only CSS but the support isn't very good since I will rely on `conic-gradient`:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:conic-gradient(red,blue,orange,yellow,green,red);
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - 21px),#fff calc(100% - 20px)); 
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - 21px),#fff calc(100% - 20px)); 
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:100%;
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:150px;"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:100px;"></div>
```

Related for more examples: [CSS Only Pie Chart - How to add spacing/padding between slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56797060/8620333)