# How to make a circle in a split background-image frame in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How to create a similar circle (image below) with JSX and can replace image into frame in Reactjs,
someone please help me, thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add your own attempt and/or the things you've tried.

Comment: sorry i'm new, and i don't know how to explain my problem better

Comment: Perhaps this will help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797060/css-only-pie-chart-how-to-add-spacing-padding-between-slices