# Round slider in html css archive different circle shapes like half arc and quarter arc shapes possible?

Tags: html, css

I have designed round slider by html and css , but based on that i want to achieve Various Circle Shapes like below link i have worked     [`round slider by HTML CSS`](https://codepen.io/fbarun/pen/QWzbYMg)

Quarter Circle [ quarter-top-left, quarter-top-right, quarter-bottom-left, quarter-bottom-right ] Half Circle [ half-top, half-bottom, half-left, half-right ]
[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799618/8620333

Comment: Hi  Temani Afif its not related.  I want like below link circular shapes https://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#events

Comment: Hi Arun, @TemaniAfif link is certainly related and well worth a read.